# Use JQuery to target Mac browsers not working

Tags: javascript, css, macos, cross-browser

I am having some small layout issues with some of my elements when I bring them up on a Mac (with all browsers).

I have created this:

```
$(function() {
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {

console.log("HERE");
    $('#topmenudisplay UL').addClass('topmenudisplaymac');
};
});
```

But it simply does not work.

I have placed this in my header below my CSS of course.

I cannot even see the console.log in my console, so the if statement is just not triggering.

Can anyone advice me on how to ammend this?

Comment: Detect browsers not OS, or better yet, detect features not browsers.

Comment: @elclanrs unless I can detect a Mac version of a browser it wont work. The issue appears isolated to Mac versions but appears fine on PC versions of the same browsers

Comment: What is the issue? Can you post a live demo? I doubt that the problem is Mac... Without knowing anything about the problem I'd say this is _highly_ unlikely.

Comment: @elclanrs The issue is the blue navigation box in the middle of the two pics sits slightly higher then it should, leaving a gap at the bottom. http://host.pixelframe.net.au/~pptestco/index.php?id=11 THis seems to only occur on mac for me - seems fine on PC

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, and I see the problem as well (in Chrome).

Comment: I would start by fixing validation errors. You're using an old DOCTYPE and you have [96 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhost.pixelframe.net.au%2F~pptestco%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D11&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) on that particular page. You can probably get rid of some errors by using  HTML5 DOCTYPE. The problem has to be an HTML/CSS issue...

Comment: Ive changed to HTML 5 but no change

Comment: Dunno, it all seems a bit messy, the HTML, the CSS and the JS. I would honestly start from scratch. Get a good grid system, use classes instead of id's, follow a semantic structure that's reusable, don't abuse `position:absolute`, and use relative units instead of pixels where possible. Test in browsers as you go, and make sure your HMTL validates as much as possible. Can't spot the problem in your current code...

Comment: Haha honestly, I would too - but this evolved from a very simple site with lots of peoples input and Im stuck with it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Seriously, do you get additional problems if you _always_ add that class to the UL, regardless of OS?